# force text to stay at bottom in coloumn bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem that i want `li` to stay at bottom coloumn not at top coloumn
here my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <p>lorem ipsum</p>
              <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="detil">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <h2>10</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

css

```
h2,p{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/vicario/pen/eZJpov

as you can see my list go to top, how i make it to go to bottom?

Comment: div > li? That's some strange markup.

Comment: ya finnaly got an answer

Answer (score 0):

just fix the bug

i only had to add class like this

```
    .row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

and set the detil to

```
.detil {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```